# Django Rest Framework APITestCase client requires format parameter

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

When trying to test apis that are decorated with `@api_view` I receive a format that does not match to the response when testing it manually. I expect the following format:

```
{
    "field": "string value"
}
```

but when I try to post(from tests) I receive error because the format appears to be this one:

```
{
    "field": ["string_value"]
}
```

To reproduce this problem:

```
class Tests(rest_framework.test.APITestCase):
    def test_api(self): 
         ...
         response = self.client.post(url, data)
         ...
```

Comment: `response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')`

Comment: This is the answer, I have other projects where I have not had the need to add the format, why is so?

Comment: Most likely your DRF parser settings. Can't really tell without looking at your views.

Comment: Checkout the answer for a more specific places where to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')`

Make sure to add this to your code. The `format='json'` part is important because I assume your endpoint is set to receive it. Your endpoint is not smart enough to recognize what format you're sending it in, but it recognizes whether it's in the format you've set it to be :) You can override this by adding a `parser_class=(JSONParser,))` or `@parser_classes((JSONParser,))` to your `APIView`/`@apiview`.

Check your `settings.py` file for this line.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    )
}
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/

Answer (score 3):

You can also set a default format in `settings.py` with:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
    ...
}
```

... Meaning you don't have to set it with each request.